# awk command with v=line number as variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables, awk

i have a file called shazad.txt
[root@ans archive]# cat shazad.txt

a

aa

aaa

aaaa

aaaaa

aaaaaa

aaaaaaa

i want to add some data at specific line number which works if i explicitly say NR==10
[root@ans archive]# awk 'NR==10{print "ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp"}1' shazad.txt

a

aa

aaa

aaaa

aaaaa

aaaaaa

aaaaaaa

aaaaaaaa

aaaaaaaaa

ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp

aaaaaaaaaa

but when i pass the value as variable it doesnt do anything, not sure what is going on

also, if there is any other way like sed to insert at a particular line using a variable name as reference.

[root@ans archive]# echo $abc

10

[root@ans archive]# awk 'NR==$abc{print
"ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp"}1' shazad.txt

a

aa

aaa

aaaa

aaaaa

aaaaaa

aaaaaaa

aaaaaaaa

aaaaaaaaa

aaaaaaaaaa

Comment: You missed the `-v` option and `$abc` is not interpreted inside single quotes. For the part with the variable use double quotes instead.

Comment: @Socowi that's not the only problem.

Comment: The $abc is not expanded when it is eclosed in single quotes.  Try `echo '$abc'`

Comment: so what can be done? is there a solution to achieve this? @Socowi

Comment: Um, yeah. The solution is in the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script). Use `awk -v n="$abc" 'NR==n {...`.